# Why is Windsor tracking some components, and some not?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I'm currently challenged by some memory leaks in our WPF application (.NET 4.0, Castle Windsor 3.2.1). Thatswhy I stumbled over an effect, I cannot explain. I thought, Windsor is tracking every resolved component by default (`LifecycledComponentsReleasePolicy`), but when I look at the debugger output, this doesn't always seem to be the case.

There are, for example, two classes (out of a bunch), like this:

```
public class ViewOne : UserControl, ITabPageView
{...}
```

and

```
public class ViewSecond : TabPageBase, ITabPageView<A>, ITabPageView
{...}
```

where:

```
public class TabPageBase : UserControl, ITabPageView
{...}
```

and

```
public interface ITabPageView<T> : ITabPageView
{...}
```

Both of the View-classes are registered via the same component registration (by convention), like this:

```
Container.Register( 
  Classes.FromThisAssembly()
    .BasedOn<ITabPageView>()
    .WithServices(typeof(ITabPageView)
    .Configure(...setting the name of the component...)
    .LifestyleTransient()
```

So, when I now resolve an instance of the first class

```
_container.Resolve<ITabPageView>("ViewOne");  // this is for explanation purposes only, not intended for production
```

I get an instance and a look into the debugger-out put of the container shows, that right this instance is 'tracked by release policy'.

When I now do the exact same thing with the name of the second class (ViewSecond), I also get a correct instance for class ViewSecond, but this doesn't show up in 'tracked by release policy'. More strange is, that some dependencies of ViewSecond are obviously tracked, but again not all of them. Some digging through the code of Windsor revealed, that instances are tracked, when their `Burden` is created with `requiresDecommission=true` and `trackedExternally=false` but I could not find a case, where `requiresDecommission` would be `true`.

Could anyone give me a hint, if there is something wrong or where I may continue my search for enabling tracking for ALL of my components? Or is the debugger output just plain wrong?

Comment: I can't explain the inconsistent behavior, but re: "but I could not find a case, where requiredDecommission would be true".... If memory serves, anything that's IDisposable is seen as having decomission concerns.  Are you base WPF classes IDisposable???

Comment: Yep, I firstly thought this, too, but UserControl doesn't implement IDisposable, after all.

Answer (score 3):

Windsor will figure out if it needs to track your objects. It may do so because the component, or one of its dependencies, implements IDisposable or for a number of other reasons. Generally you should not care why. It is really an implementation detail of the container.

You could enable tracking by using a lifestyle which requires it but I don't see this assisting with your problem.

The very simple rule with Windsor to avoid memory leaks is to Release everything you Resolve.

Comment: I know, but it seems strange to release components that aint tracked

Comment: No it's the sensible way to do things. Otherwise your code for resolving objects has to implicitly understand how they have been registered, which is a total pain. Your resolve calls should not need to understand such a thing.

Comment: +1 for pointing out, that I just should do things as supposed and not to worry about internals. Maybe this saved me from wildly digging into stuff, that shouldn't bother my code

Comment: And I must admit, that right that blog post of 2K made me look deeper into the container internals, in the first place and afterwards I was just suprised about what I saw, since it seemed contradictory.